# Add and remove score with React

Tags: reactjs

So I'm learning react and making this game project which is basically catch a fish which randomly pops out from water splash. The problem I have is adding and removing score from incorrect fish. It seems my code just does not want to select correct fish and adds incorrect score. Could you guys help me out figure it out what's wrong with this part of code ?

```
  addToScore(){
let randomIndex=Math.floor(Math.random()*picture.length); 
let selectedPicture = picture[randomIndex];
if (selectedPicture==="game__fish"){ 
  this.setState({
  score: (this.state.score - 2), 
  selectedPicture:'game__fish2',
  fishHasBeenClicked:false,
  background: '75px'
});  
} else {
    this.setState({
      score: (this.state.score + 1),
       fishHasBeenClicked:false,
       selectedPicture:'game__fish2',
       background: '75px'

      })
  }
  }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "incorrect fish"? It appears the selected fish is randomly chosen in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When incrementing/decrementing or doing any state update that ***depends*** on the previous state then you should use a *functional state update*. This takes the state from the last state update and updates from that value.

You can also further make your `addToScore` handler more DRY by combining the two `setState` and splitting the logic where it matters

```
addToScore() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * picture.length); 
  const selectedPicture = picture[randomIndex];

  this.setState(prevState => ({
    score: prevState.score + (selectedPicture === "game__fish" ? - 2 : 1), 
    selectedPicture:' game__fish2',
    fishHasBeenClicked: false,
    background: '75px'
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addToScore() {
  const selectedPicture = picture[Math.floor(Math.random() * picture.length)];

  this.setState(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    score: prev.score + (selectedPicture === "game__fish" ? - 2 : 1), 
    selectedPicture:' game__fish2',
    fishHasBeenClicked: false,
    background: '75px'
  }));
}
```